# Receiver points appear as circle around building footprints in Openoise plugin for QGIS

Tags: qgis, modelling, spatial-analysis, noise

I have been trying to get receiver points using Openoise plugin for QGIS 3.18 Zurich but they appear in a circle form around the actual building footprints.This is a Noise Modelling tool that helps to visualize the impact of sound and how it propagates from a location. Receiver points should appear as seen in the first screenshot near by the source which in this case is traffic noise levels.

[image]

When the impact of noise level is calculated we expect something the following results.

[image]

In the image below datasets where extracted from Openstreetmap and converted to shapefile format (WGS 84) but I can’t get the same results.

What could be the cause of this?

[image]

Following image shows the dialog input.

[image: Input dialog box for the Openoise plugin]

Comment: Welcom to GIS SE, Wombura Kimacha! For users here to be able to answer your question, it would be good to add additional information. To me, it is not clear what Openoise plugin is and what it does. What kind of result do you expect - if not a circle? Describe your workflow. Edit and revise your initial question to do that.

Comment: Hello @Babel thank you for you reply! I am going to edit the question to make it more clear. Once again you for your welcoming gesture.

Comment: @Babel I’ve the required changes I believe It will more clear now as to what I need from the help.

Comment: OK, so can you show what kind of input you use for the plugin (the plugin's dialog/nput settings)? You say your layer is in WGS 84 - do you mean CRS = `EPSG:4326`? This CRS uses degrees as units - so if you make any distance-settings, it is in degrees. When you input 1, it is one degree - denpending on where on Earth that is, this is a vaying distance of hundreds of km - could this be the problem?

Comment: Hello @Babel please refer to the last section of the questions edit

Comment: I removed your second question which sought a software recommendation.